# Css flex div with meta data at the bottom stretch to same height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a box with two sections, the header with image and the content at the bottom separate to two sections, the text and the action button.

The problem is the text is sometimes big and sometimes small and i need all the boxes to stretch to the same height based on the larger box.

This is my try with flex, but for some reason it does not working.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.wrapper > div {
  max-width: 25%;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.wrapper > div .img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
.wrapper > div .img img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.wrapper > div .meta {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-align-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: justify;
  align-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">

  <div>
    <div class="img">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="meta">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus tempora perspiciatis repellat minus voluptates iure ratione doloremque nulla excepturi ducimus, autem modi temporibus expedita quos eum magnam saepe facilis itaque?</p>

      <div class="action">
        <button>click me</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="img">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="meta">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus tempora perspiciatis</p>

      <div class="action">
        <button>click me</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

Notice that I have made the inner div (the direct child of `.wrapper`) `flex-direction:column`.

I have also moved the button div out of the `meta` div so that it's always at the bottom.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.wrapper > div {
  max-width: 25%;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.wrapper > div .img {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 100px;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 100px;
          flex: 0 0 100px;
}
.wrapper > div .img img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.wrapper > div .meta {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
}
.wrapper > div .action {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">

  <div>
    <div class="img">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="meta">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus tempora perspiciatis repellat minus voluptates iure ratione doloremque nulla excepturi ducimus, autem modi temporibus expedita quos eum magnam saepe facilis itaque?</p>


    </div>
    <div class="action">
      <button>click me</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="img">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="meta">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus tempora perspiciatis</p>

    </div>

    <div class="action">
      <button>click me</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```